# Java - Parse a String to a non-primitive data type text file to an integer

Tags: java, string-parsing

I'm trying to convert the string from the text file into a non-primitive data type as an integer but i get an error when i try to parse integer

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(RESOURCE))) {
                    int line_idx = 1;
                    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                        String line = sc.nextLine();
                        String[] properties = line.split(SEPARATOR, -1);
                        try {
                            Patron patron = Integer.parseInt(properties[0]);
                            Book book = Integer.parseInt(properties[1]);
                            LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(properties[2]);
                            LocalDate dueDate = LocalDate.parse(properties[3]);
                            Loan loan = new Loan(patron, book, startDate, dueDate);
                            Book.setLoan(loan);
                            Patron.addBook(book);
                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                            throw new LibraryException("Unable to parse patron id " 
                            + properties[0] + " on line " + line_idx + "\nError: " + ex);
                        }
                        line_idx++;
                    }
                }

            //Loan file
            private Patron patron;
            private Book book;
            private LocalDate startDate;
            private LocalDate dueDate;

            public Loan(Patron patron, Book book, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate dueDate) {
                this.patron = patron;
                this.book = book;
                this.startDate = startDate;
                this.dueDate = dueDate;
            }

    public Book(int id, String title, String author, String publicationYear, String publisher) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.author = author;
            this.publicationYear = publicationYear;
            this.publisher = publisher;
        }
```

Text file:

```
3::23::2019-09-23::2019-09-30::
```

Error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Patron
>   Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Book

Comment: can you post your error?

Comment: You should add the exact error and the line it's pointing to so we can better help you answer your question. Also try adding what you've tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: and also the value of the constant `SEPARATOR` please?

Comment: `Patron patron = Integer.parseInt(properties[0]);
Book book = Integer.parseInt(properties[1]);` how can you assign `int` to `Book` or `Patron`?

Comment: You Can't assign `Integer` to `Pattern and Book` object, I don't think the code is compiling.

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Patron                                            
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Book

Comment: What you need is probably a new constructor like `public Patron(int){…}` that you can call, or perhaps based on `String`, or a `static public Patron forId(int id){…}`. Either way, this is a best closed as typo or trivial mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you're trying to do you need to make a constructor for `Book` and `Patron`

```
public class Book{
    public Book(int i){
        //what to do whith the int 
    }
}
```

and then you call it like this

```
Book book = new Book(Integer.parseInt(properties[1]));
```

Comment: i already have a constructor

Comment: Create another one that accepts int as a parameter and you call it by "new Book(Integer.parseInt(properties[1]));"

Comment: in Java you can make as many constructors as you need

Comment: Did it work for you?